# Тире между существительным и субстантивным прилагательным

Tags: пунктуация, тире, существительные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли тире в предложении?

*Кирилл (—) военный, полностью обеспечивает свою семью.*

В роли подлежащего существительное, в роли сказуемого — субстантивное прилагательное, поэтому тире, думаю, надо поставить, но сомневаюсь.
У Розенталя этого не нашла, может быть, невнимательно смотрела.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Кирилл — военный, полностью обеспечивает свою семью.*

Дело в том, что слово [военный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) в этом предложении является существительным (такое значение зафиксировано в словарях):
военный, -ого; ***м.*** =Военнослужащий (тот, кто состоит на действительной военной службе).

> [**1.**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92) Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа...

*Сергей — военный в отставке, подрабатывающий охранником* (Н. Янтарная. Судьбы — как реки); *Анатолий — военный, служит по контракту во Внутренних войсках* России (из статьи).

Comment: Спасибо! Буду иметь в виду!

Comment: Рада, если удалось помочь. Заглядывайте. Если ответ для Вас полезен, то так и обозначьте (стрелочкой), если не ждете других ответов — примите (галочкой). Это и позволяет, собственно, понять, помогли Вам  или нет.